Satellite Navigation: Measuring Velocity & Position
How is the position and velocity of a satellite measured from ground? Radar measurements could give us range and range rate which are scalar quantities (if I understand this correctly). But how could the position vector of the satellite and also its velocity vector relative to a ground station be calculated/ measured?


But how could the position vector of the satellite and also its velocity vector relative to a ground station be calculated/ measured?

It can't, or not per se at least.
Except for the most sophisticated tracking arrays, one only gets an approximate direction in the sky from a single measurement (as you already understand), so the radial distance and radial velocity are not enough to get a state vector (combined position and velocity vectors).
Instead, one accumulates several tracking measurements, assumes either no non-gravitational accelerations or perhaps a constant drag term, and fits a plausible orbital trajectory to that set of measurements.

"Hmm... let's see, what orbital trajectory can fit all of these partial measurements?"

The calculation of those trajectories will certainly include the effects of Earth's oblate gravitational field, and the more sophisticated ones will even include a detailed model for Earth's lumpy gravity field, and for higher orbits (e.g. MEO, GEO and beyond), the gravitational perturbations of the Sun and Moon as well.
Those could be several measurements made over a single pass overhead (inefficient because you have to track one specific object for (at least) several minutes), or measurements made from several ground stations at different locations, or the same ground station but from more than one pass.
Ideally someone will add a more thorough answer that explores these options in more detail, and discuss how optical tracking of satellites against the stars by Baker Nunn cameras differs from radar tracking from dish antennas differs from radar via big, government phased array antennas.
